# Dependency problems prevent configuration of linux signed image

Tags: apt, kernel, updates, dpkg, update-manager

Everytime I run a software update on Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity), I see an error. And it only lists `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic` in the details.

I'm not sure how to diagnose the problem, but after a bit of searching I landed on entering `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in the terminal which results in this

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic:
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 4.4.0.47.50); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.47.50); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
 linux-generic
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The latest Ubuntu base software update seems to have fixed the issue.